# Why do Property class's decorator methods in Python return a copy of the Property object and not the object itself?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, python-descriptors

The documentation provided on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) for class **Property**, states that:

"*A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as decorators that create a copy of the property with the corresponding accessor function set to the decorated function.*"

What I can't wrap my head around is this: why make a new copy (and hence the overhead of duplication) of the existing **Property** object, with an extra accessor function set in place, and not just simply augment it (the object) by filling in that accessor function into its corresponding vacant slot (**fset** / **fdel**), and then return it, the original object itself?

Comment: This question is addressed in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python#comment49685936_17330273